# RubyMine not showing gem installed from Github with bundler

Tags: ruby, bundler, rubymine, gemfile, rubymine-7

RubyMine 7 isn't showing a gem installed from Github with bundler. For example:

- gem 'spree', '3.0.4'  - no conflict, all works
- gem 'spree', github:
  'spree/spree', branch: '~> 3.1.0.beta' - not available in "Ruby SDK and Gems"

I've tried adding a path to `.rvm/env/myenv`:

```
export GEM_PATH='/home/deface/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2:/home/deface/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global:/home/deface/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bundler/gems
```

If I click `Tools -> Show env`,

SDK Gem paths:

```
 ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bundler/gems
 ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems
 ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems
```

What's the problem? Why does the IDE not see the gems?

Comment: use exact branch name like `branch: '3.1.0.beta'` without `~>`

Comment: fatal: ambiguous argument '3.1.0.beta': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.

Comment: That should be exact value of branch or tag name of the repo

Comment: Version latest : v3.0.5

Comment: If you wish to use fixed tot , specify the ref: 'xxxxxxxxx'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Code completion from gem in git repository (RubyMine)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20782589/code-completion-from-gem-in-git-repository-rubymine)